# Sidekiq processes queues only AFTER others are done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, sidekiq

Is it possible to process jobs from a Sidekiq queue ONLY if all other queues are empty?

For example, say we have a photos queue and a updates queue. I only want to process photos if updates is free of pending jobs.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have a look see: http://tech.tulentsev.com/2012/12/queue-prioritization-in-sidekiq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all you queues execute in parallel, so I don't get the idea of executing consequentially.
But you have several options to play with:

1. you can make more concurrent workers
2. you can set frequency higher to updates queue, so updates worker will check for updates more frequently then photo worker.

Take a look at this options in [doc](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues)